# How to use Principal Component Analysis with ANN in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, pca

Variables used here:

```
trainX: 1818x13 (Input Matrix with 13 features)
trainY: 1818x1  (Output Vector)
testX and testY are corresponding variables for testing the neural network.
```

Now, I want to use PCA to reduce the number of input features because I suspect that some of the features have a certain level of correlation among themselves. So, I write the following code.

```
[pn,meanp,stdp] = prestd(trainX');
[ptrans,transMat] = prepca(pn,0.0002);

trainX = ptrans';

[pn,meanp,stdp] = prestd(testX');
[ptrans,transMat] = prepca(pn,0.0002);
testX = ptrans';

net = newfit(trainX', trainY', 45);
net.performFcn = 'mae';
net = trainlm(net, trainX', trainY');

forecast = sim(net, testX')';
```

I am getting huge errors in the `forecast` after applying PCA. I know I am doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: try to split the data in trainX and testX *after* applying the PCA transformation...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried it and it works. The error is a little more though, but I'm down to 6 features :)